# Shell Script: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I made a very simple script on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows as shown below. I even followed the tutorial and guidelines mentioned [here](http://www.panix.com/%7Eelflord/unix/bash-tute.html).

**Of that tutorial, all the scripts were working.** However, the following simple script fails:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter number: "
read number
echo "$number"
```

I ever tried a similar script:

```
#!/bin/bash
read -p "Enter number: " number
echo "$number"
```

Every time, I was getting the same error.

```
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Linux$
aps120797@XENON-PC:/mnt/d/Linux$ bash E3Q1.sh
': not a valid identifierumber
```

Note: *identifierumber above is actually = identifier + (n)umber*

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: you have `\r\n` line endings. Either set your editor you use Unix style line endings, or preprocess all files created in Windows with `dos2unix file1 file 2 ..... filen`. Good luck.

Comment: Hey, would emacs work for writing scripts?

Comment: @AbhijeetSingh emacs? emacs works for writing everything! You could even try nano, probably more friendly (and less powerful).

Comment: @linuxfan: Thanks! I fixed that problem. I used vi editor for that. Working with emacs on bash was quite difficult. So lesson learn, never use Github's Atom for Shell Scripting.

Comment: @shelter: Thanks for the help, did the same using vi editor. Worked just perfect. :)